# Using symfony/phpunit-bridge with Mink

Tags: symfony, mink

The ***symfony/phpunit-bridge*** package provides a functionality to report deprecations when running unit tests. I want to know if and how that is possible to use together with ***Mink***, i.e: to report the deprecations *encountered during the request of the Mink Session to the server*, kind of like remote coverage but for symfony deprecations instead.

Comment: Does this help?  http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-2-logging-of-deprecated-calls See the note at the bottom about parsing the log file.  I appreciate it's not exactly what you've asked, but thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/883 might also be relevant here - looks like someone's started work on just such a tool.